# ASP.NET MVC & C# : pass a viewmodel to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, viewmodel

I have a controller that passes the viewmodel to a view, and in the view it creates  the table correctly.

Then in the same page of the table I have a link that redirects the user to another page.

This new page needs to keep the viewmodel of the previous view. How could I do it?

In the view, in the table page this link that should redirect to an action of `EanMatch` controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Inserimento manuale", "Index", "EanMatch",  null, new {Vm = Model})
```

The model is this:

```
public List<DDTViewModel> DDTList { get; set; }
```

In the `EanMatchController` and `Index` action I have:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(DDTListViewModel Vm)
{
    ....
}
```

I can't understand why it doesn't work. `DDTListViewModel` Vm in `Index` actions takes 'null' value, meanwhile I have seen with debug that Model got the list of data.

How can I pass the viewmodel to the action argument correctly?

Any doubt, ask !

Comment: Is it .net core or .net framework?

Comment: it is .netframework

Comment: What is DDTListViewModel ? Is it smth that safety store on the client-side?

Comment: @staff614 you are setting the ViewModel inside a property inside an anonymous object. This is why you are not getting the result you want.

Comment: @BasilKosovan DDTListViewModel contains the list of a viewModel

public List<DDTViewModel> DDTList { get; set; }

Comment: @panoskarajohn yea, because i am actually going through attempts, I tried set it also not anonymous object and still it doesnt work

Comment: @staff614 have you tried a simple example? I have also provided an answer for you.

Comment: Html.ActionLink resolves in to an  `<a ....>` and this produces a GET request to your controller. You cannot pass a whole model with that method. You need to submit a form for that. Or use an AJAX resquest with help from JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case, You'll have to serialize your model as a JSON string, and send that to your controller to turn into an object.

Here's your `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Inserimento manuale", "Index", "EanMatch",  new { jsonModel= Json.Encode(Model.DDTListViewModel) }, null)
```

And your `Controller` method would look like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string jsonModel)
{
  var serializer= new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Model.DDTListViewModel));
  var yourmodel=  (DDTListViewModel)serializer.ReadObject(GenerateStreamFromString(jsonModel));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkName", "Index", "EanMatchController", new ViewModel { Id = 1, Name = "Sth", Description = "Hello" }, null);
```

You set the object as property to an anonymous object. 
This is why your object is not passed on the controller.

It is like having a wrapper object around your object like below.

```
public class Sth{
 public ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

So C# does not recognize this as your object you need to somehow create it inside razor and send it back to the controller. The code above works. Try a simple example.

Comment: it gives error to 'new viewModel'.

however, i tried to put new { id = 1 } and it passes the data to the action, it just doesn't work with the list of viewmodel

Comment: Pass your own view model. I just posted as an example. View model is an object with 3 properties.

Answer (score 0):

if you controller name is EanMatch, then the next issue is that I think you are passing the model in where it expects htmlattributes.  So instead of null, new {Vm = Model}; switch them.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Inserimento manuale", "Index", "EanMatch", new {Vm = Model} ,null )
```

Comment: Hit f12 and see what's being send post/get.

Comment: it posts as query string ?Capacity=16&Count=11   which I can't explain actually

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Inserimento manuale", "Index", "EanMatch",  null,  Model)
```

OR:
Each request to the server has its own context(thread) and doesn't know anything about others. If you need to share a model or another data between a few different requests to the server you can use `temp data` or `session`.
Inside of the first action, you need to save this model:

```
Session["myModel"] = Model;
```

and read in another:

```
var val = Session["myModel"];
```

Comment: Where actually should
"Session["myModel"] = Model;"  go? it is between a View to Controller, not action to action

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the anonymous object, just pass your view model:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Inserimento manuale", "Index", "EanMatch", null, Model)
```

The framework will convert your model to a query string that will be bound by your controller.